# "Action" > "Send To" in SharePoint 2013 Photo Libraries

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

After upgrade SharePoint 2010 to 2013 i missed one specific feature related to Picture Libraries.

In SP2010 there was menu with Action button where you can Send photos as attachments by Outlook. Also during process photos was automatically re sized to comfortable sizes. And you've been able to attach multiple photos.

In SP2013 whole menu is lost.

Do you have any ideas how to bring it back? Or any other ways to attach multiple photos and send by email?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is gone in SharePoint 2013. they replace it with more powerful feature called Share /Share With.

In new feature, not only send the link but also give the permission to new user(if he is new).

Other option is just copy the url when you click ellipses "..." in-front of image /file.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/send-an-email-or-copy-the-link-of-a-library-file-or-list-item-HA102771928.aspx